# Amcharts multi series line chart not displaying

Tags: amcharts4

I thought this would fairly straightforward.

I am trying to create a multi series stacked timeseries chart, at the moment I am unable to make it work with even one of the series series.

```
var rawdata = [{compoundInterest:100,
date:"2020-12-01",
investment:1000,
label:1,
lostToFees:0.25074911830097335,
returnOnInvestment:4.374847450990728
},
{
compoundInterest:104.83147148630928,
date:"2021-01-01",
investment:1100,
label:1,
lostToFees:0.5287042515940357,
returnOnInvestment:4.374847450990728
},
{
compoundInterest:105.30923247234422,
date:"2021-02-01",
investment:1200,
label:1,
lostToFees:0.8340920982343505,
returnOnInvestment:9.187179647080587
},
{
compoundInterest:105.8101368090525,
date:"2021-03-01",
investment:1300,
label:1,
lostToFees:1.167140792415239,
returnOnInvestment:14.436996588269672
},
{
compoundInterest:106.33619967408472,
date:"2021-04-01",
investment:1400,
label:1,
lostToFees:1.5280799122806457,
returnOnInvestment:20.124298274557844
},
{
compoundInterest:106.88944506118636,
date:"2021-05-01",
investment:1500,
label:1,
lostToFees:1.9171404880812588,
returnOnInvestment:26.24908470594496
},
{
compoundInterest:107.47190581876677,
date:"2021-06-01",
investment:1600,
label:1,
lostToFees:2.3345550103745154,
returnOnInvestment:32.81135588243117
},
{
compoundInterest:108.08562368863693,
date:"2021-07-01",
investment:1700,
label:1,
lostToFees:2.7805574382662144,
returnOnInvestment:39.81111180401638
},
{
compoundInterest:108.73264934491681,
date:"2021-08-01",
investment:1800,
label:1,
lostToFees:3.255383207697605,
returnOnInvestment:47.24835247070063
},
{
compoundInterest:109.41504243311283,
date:"2021-09-01",
investment:1900,
label:1,
lostToFees:3.759269239776131,
returnOnInvestment:55.123077882483805
},
{
compoundInterest:110.13487160936633,
date:"2021-10-01",
investment:2000,
label:1,
lostToFees:4.292453949148694,
returnOnInvestment:63.435288039366114
}]

am4core.ready(function() {


  am4core.addLicense("xxxxxxxx");
   

    var projectionChart = am4core.create("projectionchartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
    var chartData = rawdata;
  
    for (i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
        chartData[i].date = new Date(chartData[i].date);
    }

var projectionChart = am4core.create("profitabilitychartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
projectionChart.data = chartData;
var dateAxis = projectionChart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

// Create value axis
var valueAxis = projectionChart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
valueAxis.title.text = "$";

// Create series
var series = projectionChart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.valueY = "compoundInterest";
series.fillOpacity = 0.3;

});
```

Currently it just renders an SVG with empty g tags.
Can anyone point me in the direction of where I'm going wrong?
I am somewhat inexperienced with amcharts and I'm flumoxxed.

Thank You